# Sprng MVC Thymeleaf href broken

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dark Flower Store - 闇の花屋</title>
</head>
<body>
<a th:href="@{/books}">Books</a>
<a href="/bookstore/books">Books</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The second link works properly, while the first one becomes a plain text.

That link in page source also shows exactly what I typed in the code, instead of being converted to a link.

Here's the HomeController:

```
package com.hanabinoir.bookstore;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

and the dependencies in the pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

There is a NullPointerException error when eclipse STS is loading the workplace, and few errors related to JPA when I started up the server.

> ERROR 677804 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful:
>   drop table book ERROR 677804 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Schema 'SA' does not exist

Comment: Do you have a working Thymeleaf setup?

Comment: Your HTML looks correct.  Do you see any errors on startup?  Can you please post your config and controller code?  Otherwise, check the docs to see where your config is off.

Comment: @bphilipnyc There are several errors related to JPA when I start up the server, and a NullPointerException when eclipse STS is loading the workplace. I've posted the controller and pom dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After moving the **index.html** file from **/webapp** folder to **/templates** folder, the Thymeleaf engine finnally works.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to keep your href working even offline--That is by viewing your html files without running the application.

```
<a href='book.html' th:href="@{/books}">Books</a>
```

Keep note that when the application is running it will render th:href attribute and disregard the plain href. But when your offline, html will not recognize all the attributes the th: attrib and only the plain href works.

It works in CSS and  too.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}">

<script src="../static/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" th:src="@{/js/jquery-1.10.2.js}"></script>
```

That's one of the advantages of using Thymeleaf from other templates like JSP and the like.